# Sending a list of arrays to a For loop

Tags: python, list, iteration

Is it possible to send a list of numpy arrays to a for loop in Python and then have it iterate over each one? A psuedo-example:

```
apples = [red, green]
for type in apples:
    print type
```

Where red and green are arrays containing a list of different varieties of red and green apples? Currently it only will print 'red' and 'green' but I want the loop to be able to access the arrays. Pretty new to Python so please forgive if this is a simple question! Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
apples = [red, green]
for type in apples:
    for item in type:
        print item
```

This will loop over the lists inside the main list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import chain
for item in chain.from_iterable(apples):
    print item
```

If you need to know the "type" during the iteration, you should use two explicit loops and @Simeon suggests